# Neo4j cypher query: AllShortestPaths with specified nodes and relationship properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

i'm new to neo4j.

I created this example:

```
//         (Node2)
//         /     \
//   Rel2 /       \ Rel3
//       /         \
// (Node1) ------> (Node3)
//          Rel1
// 
// create nodes
CREATE
(n1:Node1{id:1,rights:["admin","user"]}),
(n2:Node2{id:2,rights:["admin","user"]}),
(n3:Node3{id:3,rights:["admin","user"]})
// create relationships
CREATE (n1)-[r1:Rel1{id:11,rights:["admin"]}]->(n3)
CREATE (n1)-[r2:Rel2{id:12,rights:["admin","user"]}]->(n2)
CREATE (n2)-[r3:Rel3{id:13,rights:["admin","user"]}]->(n3)
RETURN n1,n2,n3,r1,r2,r3
```

Each node and relationship has a property array with some rights values. 
I want to create a query that gives me (shortest) paths between two nodes with specified properties.
Example:

User has rights 'admin', the path should be:

(Node1)-[Rel1]->(Node3) 
(Each node and releationship has the 'admin' String in the 'rights' property.)

If the user has the right 'user', the path should be:

(Node1)-[Rel2]-(Node2)-[Rel3]-(Node3)
(Because the Rel1 relation didn't have the 'user' String in the 'rights' property.)

At first i tried this query that worked:

```
WITH ["admin","otherRight"] AS usersRights
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((n1:Node1{id:1})-[*..4]-(n2:Node3{id:3})) 
WITH *, relationships(path) AS rels, nodes(path) as nodes
WHERE ANY (rel IN rels WHERE ANY(r IN rel.rights WHERE r IN usersRights))
AND ANY (node IN nodes WHERE ANY(r IN node.rights WHERE r IN usersRights))
RETURN path
```

Then i replaced the 'admin' with 'user', but this query didn't work (has no rusults):

```
WITH ["user","otherRight"] AS usersRights
MATCH ... // same as above
...
RETURN path
```

The follwing query matches my needed result, but in this case, 
i would have to make several queries to get the desired result (shortest paths) for depth n.

```
WITH ["user","otherRight"] AS usersRights
MATCH path=(n1:Node1{id:1})-[r1]-(n2)-[r2]-(n3:Node3{id:3}) 
WHERE ANY(r IN n1.rights WHERE r IN usersRights)
AND ANY(r IN r1.rights WHERE r IN usersRights)
AND ANY(r IN n2.rights WHERE r IN usersRights)
AND ANY(r IN r2.rights WHERE r IN usersRights)
AND ANY(r IN n3.rights WHERE r IN usersRights)
RETURN path
```

Is it possible to create a cypher query that gives me the disired results ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query has a `WITH` clause separating the `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses, which prevents the `WHERE` clause from affecting the behavior of the `allshortestpath()` function. Therefore, the function was just returning the shortest path(s) without testing the nodes and relationships.

Try this, instead:

```
WITH ["admin","otherRight"] AS usersRights
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((n1:Node1{id:1})-[*..4]-(n2:Node3{id:3})) 
WHERE
  ANY (rel IN relationships(path) WHERE ANY(r IN rel.rights WHERE r IN usersRights)) AND
  ANY (node IN nodes(path) WHERE ANY(r IN node.rights WHERE r IN usersRights))
RETURN path;
```

Comment: I optimized / changed the query from 'any' to 'all', so that every relationship and node applies to the 'rights' where clause. 
WHERE
  ALL(rel IN relationships(pa... AND
  ALL (node IN nodes...
RETURN path;